# Docker container rake file error

Tags: docker, passenger

I am trying to run docker container for development environment. I am using the below docker file

```
FROM phusion/passenger-ruby22:latest
# Set correct environment variables.
ENV HOME /root

# Use baseimage-docker's init system.
CMD ["/sbin/my_init"]

# Expose Nginx HTTP service
EXPOSE 80

# Start Nginx / Passenger
RUN rm -f /etc/service/nginx/down

# Remove the default site
RUN rm /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default

# Add the nginx site and config
ADD nginx.conf /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/webapp.conf
ADD rails-env.conf /etc/nginx/main.d/rails-env.conf

# Install bundle of gems
WORKDIR /tmp
ADD Gemfile /tmp/
ADD Gemfile.lock /tmp/
RUN bundle install

# Add the Rails app
ADD . /home/app/webapp
RUN chown -R app:app /home/app/webapp

# Clean up APT and bundler when done.
RUN apt-get clean && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/*
```

nginx.conf as below

```
# webapp.conf

server {
  listen 80;
  server_name localhost;
  root /home/app/webapp/public;
  passenger_enabled on;
  passenger_user app;
  passenger_ruby /usr/bin/ruby2.2;
}
```

and Rails Env file as below,

```
# rails-env.conf

# Set Nginx config environment based on
# the values set in the .env file

env PASSENGER_APP_ENV;
env RAILS_ENV;
env SECRET_KEY_BASE;
env APP_DEV_DB_HOST;
env APP_DEV_DB_DATABASE;
env APP_DEV_DB_PORT;
env APP_DEV_DB_USERNAME;
env APP_DEV_DB_PASSWORD;
```

I kept DB(MySQL) outside the container and binded with VM IP address.

After building the docker image, now I am trying to run `rake db:setup` but I get the message as below,

```
sudo docker run -i -t -e "RAILS_ENV=development" -e "APP_DEV_DB_HOST=myipaddress" -e "APP_DEV_DB_DATABASE=SampleApp_Development" -e "APP_DEV_DB_PORT=3306" -e "APP_DEV_DB_USERNAME=sampleapp_dev" -e "APP_DEV_DB_PASSWORD=pass_dev" -e  "PASSENGER_APP_ENV=development" sample_base rake db:setup

rake aborted!
    No Rakefile found (looking for: rakefile, Rakefile, rakefile.rb, Rakefile.rb)

    (See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

At the same time if I run this using bash, I am able to run `rake db:setup` within the container

Curious to know what is causing this issue!.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I expect it's because your `WORKDIR` is set to `/tmp`; try setting it to `/home/app/webapp` after `RUN bundle install`.

I also noticed the following:

- This line won't save any space `RUN apt-get clean && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/*`; the files will still exist in previous layers.
- You override the CMD instruction (`CMD ["/sbin/my_init"]`) at runtime; so whatever's in this script won't be run.